# A different number of downvotes

Tags: support, user-profile-page, down-votes

Into my personal page I have voted down only 4-times.

[image: f]

Why do I have 14 votes down?

[image]

Comment: How did you come to see the indication `votes cast (19238)`, I looked on my profile, I couldn't find this same information!

Comment: @AndréC This link should work (for you only; other users need to put their own user ID there): https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/138900?tab=votes

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I don't see anything. Maybe it's something you can't see below 20,000 reputation?

Comment: @AndréC I don't think so; stuff in your profile should be viewable at all times (I'm not 100% sure). Try this one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/138900?tab=votes&sort=downvote or this one:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/138900/andréc?tab=votes&sort=downvote.  If neither works, then I don't know

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I don't see the "all time", "by type", etc. columns.

Comment: @AndréC Oh, that. Sorry, I misunderstood. Go to: https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/138900/andr%c3%a9c?tab=topactivity and scroll to the bottom of the page

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Ah yes, thank you, I can see everything :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The “all time” counter tells the total number of times you downvoted (without reverting later), but the 5 votes listed under the “Votes” tab only show votes on posts which still exist: the other 9 posts you downvoted were deleted after your vote.

Comment: Ah, I have understood. Thank you veryyyyyyyy much.

Comment: Very kind Phelype, this morning at the sea (splash ) I was thinking about it. I don't remember giving all these bad grades. But are spam (-1) or rude/abusive (-1) also counted?

Comment: @Sebastiano According to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/383578), when you flag a post as spam/abusive, the vote is cast by the [Community user](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community), so it doesn't add to your vote count.